# Closure of JavaScript function parameters, depending on how a function is passed as a parameter I see two different outcomes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, closures

I believe I am running into a closure issue when passing a function as a parameter of my function. I am including two snippets that I'm not quite sure are giving different results

At top of the file:

```
let printPizza = () => console.log('pizza')
```

```
function closureQuestion(fn) {
 printPizza = () => console.log('hamburger')
 fn()
}
```

These have to be run in order or printPizza gets mutated and has to be redefined

```
closureQuestion(printPizza)
```

^ logs pizza (not sure why)

```
closureQuestion(() => printPizza())
```

^ logs hamburger

Any help would be appreciated, I've read through a few example of closures (just a guess of what I'm running into) and I'm not understanding.

Comment: In the first case you have direct reference to the function that prints `pizza`. In the second, you don't and you alter the function that will be called before it's called.

Comment: @VLAZ is it possible to elaborate more? in the second example am I not using a reference to the function?

Comment: Not a *direct* reference. You have an indirect one, because you pass an anonymous function that will call `printPizza`. However, `printPizza` can change between the anonymous function being created and the anonymous function being called. The first example is like giving somebody a document to print. The document won't change - printing is always the same. The second is like giving them a URL: `www.myDocument.com` will stay the same but the content can change, so what you print may differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, you're getting the value of `printPizza` *before* you call the function. The parameter `fn` is set to the original value of `printPizza`, and reassigning the variable has no effect on the parameter. It's no different from doing:

```
let printPizza = 1;
let fn = printPizza;
printPizza = 2;
console.log(fn); // this will log 1, not 2
```

In the second version, you're not evaluating `printPizza` until the callback function is executed, so it will use the latest value of the variable.

Comment: But aren't functions passed by reference. Since printPizza is being manipulated, shouldn't fn() print a different result?

Comment: @TusharShahi: JavaScript is a *pass-by-value* language. This has nothing to do with objects being reference-type values.

Comment: @FelixKling compare the two functions inside closureQuestions using '==='. They are equal. Check https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/QWpJreG?editors=1112

Comment: @TusharShahi: Yes, but that has nothing to do with what you were asking about. Assigning to `printPizza` doesn't change the value of `fn`, because JavaScript is pass/assign by value. `fn` gets a copy of the value of `printPizza`, it doesn't get a reference to the `printPizza` *variable*.

Comment: It has because, === is true for two objects only when they refer to the same address. {} === {} is false. You are saying that if a pass an object in a function and change one of its property that will not be reflected on the original object?

Comment: You're not changing the property of an object, you're assigning to a variable. It's the difference between `a = 10` and `a.property = 10`